# Store a "routine" which, given some input, generates a 3d model

Tags: language-agnostic, dynamically-generated, 3d-model

Well, it's the time of the year were I get busy on my next-generation, cutting edge, R&D project (just for the fun of it...and maybe some profit eventually).

This time, I've had a great idea for a service, which unfortunately I can't detail much.

However, a major part of this project is the ability to generate a 3d model out of certain input criteria. The generated model must be different on each generation.

As such, this is much different than the static models used in games - I think I will have to store actual code more than just model coords.

To give an example of some output:

```
var apple = new AppleGenerator();
apple->set_size_between(30, 50); // these two numbers are just samples...
apple->set_seeds_between(3, 8); // apple must have at least 3 seeds*
var apple_model = apple->generate();

// * I realize seeds may not be exactly part of the model, but I can't of anything else
```

So I need to tackle some points here:

1. How do I store these models as data?
2. Do you know of any tools that may help?
3. I need to incorporate a randomness factor (for example, the apples would have slightly different shapes each time)
4. I suppose math will play a good part here, but since these are complex shapes, it's going to be infeasible to cook up the necessary formulae for each model, right?
5. Also, textures must be relevant to each part of the model, as well as making the model look random (eg; I could be detailing a 40 to 60 percent red, and  the rest green, for the generated apple).

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact not a simple task. The solution varies a LOT depending on the complexity and variety of the objects you are trying to create.

Let's consider a few cases though:

**Object is more or less known:**

The most simple case is, to have a 3d model in the conventional way, and then randomize it a bit. Take the apple for example. The randomization can vary from the size of the apple to its texture colors to fruit damage.

**All your objects can be described using NURBS surfaces:**

In this case, you need to store enough data for the surface to be able to be generated, where of course this data can be randomized a bit.

**Your objects have rotational symmetry:**

In this case, generating a single curve and rotating it around the an axis can give you a shape. An apple is an example. You would need to store only the curve data and randomizing the shape could either be done on the curve (keeping symmetry) or on the final mesh.

### On textures

This is way more complicated than the mesh generation. This is mainly because textures carry much more information than meshes (they are more detailed). You can have many texture generation strategies. In the case of your apple, you could select a few vertices, give them colors (one red, one green, another red etc) and interpolate the other vertex colors. This creates a smooth transition of colors which may look nice on an apple. If you are generating a knife however that just looks terrible.

In most cases, you need to be aware of which part of your mesh represents what, and generate the texture part by part. In the knife example above, you can generate the mesh in two steps; blade and handle each part's texture generated separately.

### Conclusion

You can have a mixture of these of course. A `meshGenerator` class can take the data and based on whichever type they are, generates a mesh accordingly. Perhaps the first solution for object creation is the most suitable as any complicated object can be more easily defined by its triangles rather than NURBS.

Comment: While the project itself does not rely on these 3d models, it would be a very useful addon (actually, a major feature, but still separate from the project). To be honest, I'm still analysing the situation, since it may even have to require merging objects together (eg, the seeds inside the apple being models themselves).

Comment: @Christian, If you have time to write a good library for this, I think it would be great. You might want to make it a free library and put it on github and try to find collaborators to work on it. (Also, make sure you make it GPL and not LGPL)

Comment: The best way is probably to start thinking the big picture (broad interface), but implement small stuff first. Otherwise, extending the library would be quite troublesome.

Comment: Also, [Diego's link on spore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916773/912144) is quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some of the basic architectural principles used to code *Spore*, the video game about evolving living creatures: http://chrishecker.com/My_liner_notes_for_spore

Here's an example of how to XML-serialize a mesh, along with some random morph behavior: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Morph+animation#The_XML_format_of_meshes_with_morph_animation

To make your apples all a bit different, you can apply a random transformation (or deformation). See for example: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/MeshDeform

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an established file format to avoid strange problems. It's more geometry than pure math. Your generate function would plot the polygons, and then your save method would interact with the formats.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441388/most-common-3d-model-format